# Linq-to-sql foreign key id not added automatically

Tags: c#, database, linq-to-sql, foreign-key-relationship

I have a service-based file database. With two table:
Client and Visitation. There is a One-to-Many relationship between tables: one client -> many visitations

**Tables:**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Clients] (
    [Id]          INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Surname]     NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [Firstname]   NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [Birthday]    DATETIME       NULL,
    [Email]       NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [PhoneNumber] NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [Job]         NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [Note]        NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [Birthplace]  NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Visitationdb] (
    [Id]        INT      IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [StartTime] DATETIME NULL,
    [ClientId]  INT      NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Visitationdb_ToClients] FOREIGN KEY ([ClientId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Clients] ([Id])
);
```

I created the required ClientId column and foreign key constraint.

**Linq-to-SQL**

Added new Linq to SQL classes (dbml) file to the project and created the tables' classes with the help of the designer. (Here I have to modify one-to-one relationship to one-to-many)

**Problem**

```
DataContext MdpContext = new DataContext(Settings.Default.mdcdbConnectionString); //creating the context
var c = new Client //creating new client
    {
        Birthday = patientold.Birthday,
        Email = patientold.Email,
        Firstname = patientold.FirstName,
        Job = patientold.Job,
        PhoneNumber = patientold.PhoneNumber,
        Surname = patientold.SurName,
    };
clients.InsertOnSubmit(c);
MdpContext.SubmitChanges(); //now I will have my auto generated client id set by database       
var visit = new Visitationdb {StartTime = visitold.StartTime};
c.Visitationdb.Add(visit);
MdpContext.SubmitChanges();
```

EXCEPTION THROWN:
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ClientId', table 'MDCDB.MDF.dbo.Visitationdb'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

**Questions**

Why L2S not handling inserting the ClientId automatically at line c.Visitationdb.Add(visit)?
Why do I have to SubmitChanges() every time I need an auto generated Id, is there any solution to handle all the new rows Ids and foreign keys by the framework after I added all clients and visitation?

Thank you for reading my question. Have a good coding!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the problem!

I thought that L2S handle the relationship (association) and correctly generate the entity after drag and drop into the designer.

**Problem**
In L2S instead of foreign key (ClientId) the Visitaitondb.Id was set in the Association.

**Solution**
Click on the Relation (Association) in the designer and at Properties / Participating Properties set the correct database fields. In my case: Client.Id -> Visitationdb.ClientId

Don't have to call SubmitChanges every time you need a generated Id or added a new entity. At the end all ids will be set correctly by L2S!

Comment: Tried with a completely new table and everything worked fine automatically. Maybe the problem only occurs when you generate classes with L2S and later modify the foreign key.

Comment: Your last line: no need to call SubmitChanges all the time is a very important one...